# CSS Filter is not apply to the Chrome browser

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Filter property in ccs file is applys to Internet explorer but the same filter property is not apply to the chrome browser.

Here the Filter property is:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient
 (GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#ffffffff',EndColorStr
```

Can any one please provide solution to how to enable filters for chrome browser.

Comment: Look at `linear-gradient`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#ffffffff',EndColorStr
```

is a Microsoft based css filter code and will only work on IE. Try using

```
linear-gradient()
```

instead or have a look at these other CSS3 mixins to help you out

[Compass Linear Mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/gradient/)